# Prescribed way to compute Julia sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

For computing, at least computationally, the Julia set of the mapping $z_n = z_{n-1}^2 + c$, one only needs to follow that $|z_n|\leq 2$ for all $n$, as in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Quadratic_polynomials) page.

Now, if I have a quadratic rational function

$$
f(z) = \frac{a_0 + a_1z + a_2z^2}{b_0 + b_1z + b_2z^2},
$$

what would be the equivalent condition to find the Julia set?

How this condition is derived?

Comment: Your starting point should be all possible critical points.  In $z^2+c$, the only critical point is $0$, so that is the only starting point that you must consider.  Perhaps your quadratic rational function has more than one critical point; if so you must consider them all.

Comment: How do you derive then that a point in the julia set must fulfill $|z|\leq 2$?

Comment: This map does not have a singular point at infinity (resp. $1/f(1/z)$ at $z=0$) so there is no Fatou set where the points grow over all bounds. So you can not take "escape to infinity" as coloring criterion. You could still play the "chaos game" with the inverse map, that is in each step randomly select a pre-image, to get the shape of the Julia set.

Comment: A very innocent question. I need a point in the Julia set. According to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Quadratic_polynomials), a repelling periodic point is one member. From my map, how do I determine the periodic points?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Iterations_in_the_complex_plane/analysis